# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -1310 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Object invalid or no longer set

Tags: php, html, ms-access, pdo

I am a beginner using PDO and php in general, and I'm soon out of hairs to pull out for this one.

Been debugging for eternity and cannot seem to find the reason behind this error. Can anyone spot my error?

Basically I'm trying to update two tables in the same submit form. I seem to successfully pass all the data from my index.php to my update-inc.php, but I can't manage to execute two statements in the same submit. I have pinpointed the error to happen at my first `$stmt->execute();`. If I comment out the stuff for my 2nd table it works, but I cannot figure out why.

This is also the first time I'm submitting a coding question to StackOverflow like this, so if I've left anything out please let me know! :)

Full error code: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -1310 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Object invalid or no longer set. (SQLExecute[-1310] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:263) Code: HY000`

**update-inc.php**

```
try {
        
        require_once "dbh-inc.php"; //Get db connection
        
        //echo '<script> var message = "update-inc: "+'.json_encode($postId).'; alert(message);</script>';
        
        
        // ------- QUERY HERE --------
        $query ="";
        $oeId=0;
        
            foreach($postId as $key=>$value){
                $tempQuery ="";
                $tempQuery2 ="";
                
                ${"t".$key} = "UPDATE ". $mainTable . " SET";
                
                if($value != null){
                    ${"t".$key} .= " Title = :newTitle".$key .",";
                }
                $tempQuery .= ${"t".$key};
                
                if($value != null){
                    ${"t".$key} = $tempQuery . " CopyText = :newText".$key;
                }
                
                ${"t".$key} .= " WHERE id = :id". $key ."; ";
                $tempQuery2 .= ${"t".$key};
                
                
                $query = $tempQuery2;
                

                if($oeId < 1){
                    
                    $oeQuery = 'UPDATE '. $opEnTable .' SET
                    opening = :newOpening, ending = :newEnding 
                    WHERE id = :oeId;';
                    
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($oeQuery);
                    
                    $stmt->bindValue(':oeId', $opEnId[$oeId], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':newOpening', $newOpening[$opEnId], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':newEnding', $newEnding[$opEnId], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    
                    echo "I'm getting here";
                    $stmt->execute();
                    // but not here
                    
                    $stmt->closeCursor();
                    $oeId++;
                }
                
                
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
                
                if($newTitle != null){
                    $stmt->bindValue(':newTitle'.$key, $newTitle[$key]);
                }

                if($newText != null){
                    $stmt->bindValue(':newText'.$key, $newText[$key]);
                }
                $stmt->bindValue(':id'.$key, $key);
                
                //echo '<script> alert("query: '.$query.'\nkey: '.$key.'\n\nnewTitle: '.$newTitle[$key].'");</script>';
                
                $stmt->execute();
                

                $db = null;
                $stmt = null;               
            }
```

**dbh-inc.php**

```
<?php
$dbStr = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\QuickCopy\QC1.accdb';
$mainTable = "main";
$opEnTable = "openingEnding";

if( !file_exists($dbStr) ){
    die("Could not find database file.");
}

$dsn = 'odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
    DBQ='.$dbStr.';';

try {
    
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Aside from the actual issue, why on earth are you using Access as the back-end for a web application? It's simply isn't designed for it, or suitable for it. This will just be your first headache of many. I suggest using something like MySQL, or even SQLite would be better.

Comment: Honestly? I needed a database and noticed Access was installed by default on my work laptop, figured I'd try it and went with it. Haha... There are a bunch of restrictions in my company. I guess MySQL should be approved too since XAMPP was. Should I rewrite?

Comment: If this app is going to be used by more than, say, 2 people then I'd say yes absolutely. And it will just generally be easier to work with other database platforms via PDO. If you got XAMPP installed then you likely already have MySQL or MariaDB installed and available.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at this. For curiosity's sake, do you know why I'm getting the error?

Comment: To be honest no I don't. But Access is a law unto itself so I don't rate your chances of fixing it easily

Comment: What's your OS? It's been a few years since I worked with Access from PHP, but I remember the Microsoft ODBC driver for Windows was full of quirks and completely abandoned.